# How to specify devise_parameter_sanitizer for edit action?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I've added Devise to my Rails 4 application, and successfully added username etc. to my User model. Furthermore, I'm able to store those fields using the lazy way™, i.e.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :firstname, :middlename, :lastname) } 
    end
end
```

However, I tried

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :firstname, :middlename, :lastname) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:edit) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :firstname, :middlename, :lastname) }
end
```

but that didn't work quite as expected (username not being stored when invoked by the edit action). Is there something else I need to do in order to get that to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

## Deprecated Answer

This answer is not correct for the latest version of Rails or Devise.

Once again, it was a matter of reading the manual ...

The magic word is `:account_update` and thus the working version becomes

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :firstname, :middlename, :lastname, :nickname) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :firstname, :middlename, :lastname, :nickname) }
end
```

Note that if you're in the business of signing in using non-standard parameters, the word you're looking for is `:sign_in` (as expected).

Comment: This answer is deprecated. Please see the next highest rated answer.

Answer (score 80):

## For Devise 4.1+

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base    
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :email])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, bank_attributes: [:bank_name, :bank_account]])
  end
end
```

The `.for` method is deprecated, now we use `.permit`

The first arg is the action name. `:sign_up` is for creating new Devise resources (such as users), and `:account_update` is for editing/updating the resource.

The second arg, `:keys` contains an array of the parameters you allow.

If you want `nested_attributes`, there is an example in `:account_update`, you put a separate array in with the key being `<object>_attributes`.

Comment: Upgrading Rails right now, and devise, thanks for this answer.

Comment: Thanks. Also here's the link for doc of [class `ParameterSanitizer`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/devise/4.2.0/Devise/ParameterSanitizer).

Comment: Thanks. It was very important to change the name "for" to "permit", to break things, and be un backward compatible...

Answer (score 16):

@conciliator is correct about the magic word is :account_update but here's the link to the documentation he alluded to http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/
Search for 'devise_parameter_sanitizer' and you'll see the following:

There are just three actions in Devise that allows any set of parameters to be passed down to the model, therefore requiring sanitization. Their names and the permitted parameters by default are:

```
sign_in (Devise::SessionsController#new) - Permits only the authentication keys (like email)
sign_up (Devise::RegistrationsController#create) - Permits authentication keys plus password and password_confirmation
account_update (Devise::RegistrationsController#update) - Permits authentication keys plus password, password_confirmation and current_password
```

Comment: what about password update? on `PasswordsController`?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa :reset_password (the `@permitted` hash on the controller object lists what actions are used/available).

Answer (score 7):

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email,   :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :firstname, :middlename, :lastname, :nickname) }
end
```

Comment: This ":account_update" is what I was looking for. Is there a comprehensive list of all these actions?

Comment: @LaszloTenki I'd suggest this is the place to look http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/ParameterSanitizer