# "Edit user" form not saving custom field "username" in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise to implement user authentication, and I've added a custom "username" field. I was able to get the user registration form to edit the username field by putting this code in my application controller:

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
```

Now I'm trying to implement another form to edit an already existing user account, and now that form won't work for editing a user's username field.

I have a hunch that I need to add another line of code in the "configure_permitted_parameters" method above, but I tried out things like "devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << : account_update" and it didn't work.

What should I do to get the "update account" form to edit usernames?  Like I said, the "new user signup" form is working fine in that regard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify devise\_parameter\_sanitizer for edit action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791531/how-to-specify-devise-parameter-sanitizer-for-edit-action)

Comment: Thank you to both wacko and Simone.  That question (or more accurately, that answer) was EXACTLY what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this line to the "configure_permitted_parameters" method did the trick:

```
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :username
```

Comment: I have this, and it still won't work. 

My username is the string `/edit` even though it's actually blank on the records