# Ruby on Rails: Error adding additional fields to devise user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

i am trying to add the fields 'first name', 'last name' and 'phone'. However, i always get this error when revisiting local host:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#new

undefined method `configure_permitted_parameters' for #<Devise::RegistrationsController:0x00000101fcd008>
```

This is what i did:

first, i created a registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, :only => [:create]

  protected



       def configure_permitted_parameters
            devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
        end
end
```

then, i ran:

```
rails g migration AddFieldsToUsers first_name:string last_name:string phone:int
```

followed by:

```
rake db:migrate
```

in the terminal...

i then went and added

```
      t.string :first_name,
      t.string :last_name,
      t.integer :phone,
```

in the devise create users migration file.

i also tried replacing add_column to t.string in my AddFieldsToUsers migration file:

```
class AddFieldsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    t.string :users, :first_name, :string
    t.string :users, :last_name, :string
    t.integer :users, :phone, :int
  end
end
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help figure this out thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**First - [about migration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html):**

```
class AddFieldsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :first_name, :string
    add_column :users, :last_name, :string
    add_column :users, :phone, :integer
  end
end
```

> $ rake db:migrate

**Second - about permissions in rails4:**

this helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/a/19793371/3563993
and [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-devise-revised)

***application_contoller.rb***

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  ...

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :fone) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :first_name, :last_name, :fone) 
  end
end
```

Comment: Havent gotten it yet, however a new error does occur. ('NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new') and this bit of code is highlighted: <%= f.text_field :fist_name, :placeholder => "First Name", class: "form-control" %>

Comment: @Taimur K Naziri I think your table users not have first_name, do First step and run: rake db:migrate

Answer (score 0):

Put first_name,last_name, phone, after attr_accessible: in user class.
If You are using rails 3

Comment: I am using Rails 4, there is no attr_accessible, it is replaced by strong_params

Comment: Please look this link, i think it will helpful you..http://www.jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html

Answer (score 0):

You should add action `configure_permitted_parameters` in application controller as per devise [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
end
```

Your error directly indicates that you did not have `configure_permitted_parameters` method for new action.