# Devise token auth: what format for update user json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to update a user via PUT to /auth

via the docs:

`Account updates. This route will update an existing user's account settings. The default accepted params are password and password_confirmation, but this can be customized using the devise_parameter_sanitizer system. If config.check_current_password_before_update is set to :attributes the current_password param is checked before any update, if it is set to :password the current_password param is checked only if the request updates user password.`

It clearly needs something beyond just password and password_params as an identifier but neither `email`, `id`, or `uid` work. Also tried submitting with root user ie:

`{
  "user": {
    "email": ""
  }
}`

but this also does not work.

I cannot figure out what this is expecting. Not sure if I am missing something obvious. Could anyone give me an example of the json format which this is expecting?

Comment: I don't use Devise Token Auth (just plain old Devise), but what they are referring to is a Devise method `devise_parameter_sanitizer` which you must call and specify what properties of the user object are allowed to be updated. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19791531/398606).

Comment: The format of the JSON object it's expecting is the usual format in rails, for example: `{ user: { email: 'f@foo.com', name: 'fred' } }`

Comment: @SunilD. could you leave that as an actual answer? I'll try it later and if it works I will accept it