# Adding a new field causes an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

In my registration page i have 2 field, with email and password, now i trying to add new field with name, so to file `/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb` and `/app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb`i added

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
<%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", :autofocus => true %>
</div>
```

and after this edit my website show this error:

```
 Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
```

My `new.html.erb` :

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><h2>Registration</h2></div>
    <div class="panel-body">


<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', :autofocus => true %>
          </div>



          <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>



  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
    </div>
      <div class="panel-footer"><%= render "devise/shared/links" %></div>

    </div>
```

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

__Edit

after restart heroku i get new error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:11:in `configure_permitted_parameters'
```

my: `/app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


  protected


  def configure_permitted_parameters

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name

  end
end
```

Comment: Please share the full error

Comment: edited, after restart new unknown error ;/

Answer (score 2):

Try this, This will helping you.

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
  end
end
```

or follow this links, [follow](http://www.peoplecancode.com/tutorials/adding-custom-fields-to-devise)

Comment: @forschool If I solved your problem please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password,:name) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password,:name) }
  end
end
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19793371/7046734)

Hope This Helps..

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `for' for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x007f0b4aba12e0>):