# Why update_attributes doesn't update an attribute, but update does?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, puma, ruby-2.4

**Rails version:**
Rails 5.1.1

**Ruby Version:**
ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]

**Local Server:**

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.4.0-p0), codename: Private Caller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
```

I have a existing model called `User` and later I added the attribute `last_name`.

Then, trying to update the newly created field(last_name) with other fields, I used:

```
user.update_attributes(first_name: 'praaveen', last_name:'vr')
```

For `update_attributes`, this updates `first_name` but *not* the `last_name` attribute:

**rails log:**

```
UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = $1, "first_name" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["updated_at", "2017-09-20 14:19:26.174311"], ["first_name", "praaveen"], ["id", 156]]
```

I then tried with:

```
user.update(first_name: 'praaveen', last_name:'vr')
user.update_columns(first_name: 'praaveen', last_name:'vr')
```

These methods update `first_name` *and* `last_name` as expected.

**rails log:**

```
UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = $1, "first_name" = $2, "last_name" = $3 WHERE "users"."id" = $4  [["updated_at", "2017-09-20   14:15:23.623292"], ["first_name", "praaveen"], ["last_name", "vr"], ["id", 156]]
```

Any idea what's going?

Adding few observations

a. It updates random like once in 10 or 15 times update.

b. Any problem with puma multi threading?

Comment: That's strange since [`update_attributes` is just an `alias` of `update`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L289) do you have anything suspect in the model, that might have redefined that method or something?

Comment: @SimpleLime I don't have any like attr_accessible define in my User model.

Comment: @praaveen is `update_attributes` overwritten somewhere? Can you try calling `User. reset_column_information` just before the `update_attributes` statement (only for testing purposes)?

Comment: @ulferts Not overwritten

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a JSONB field that wouldn't want to be saved with `update` and not even with `update_attribute`...

I ended up marking the field to be updated with:

```
attribute_name_will_change!
```

And that worked!
Hopefully this may help someone one day.

Answer (score 0):

You might be facing some accessors trouble as described [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes).

As explained in the article:

> Doing the following will merrily return true, but will not update the
>   status attribute.
>
> @user.update_attributes(:status => 'active')

Comment: Thanks @Fabio But i don't have any like  attr_accessible  define in my User model.

Comment: The accessors are prescriptive.. I will have a guess that you are using the Devise Gem, so you could configure it with the described in this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19793371/4604645

Comment: @fabio Devise not on this model