# Rails controllers not recieving POST parameters sent from Next.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, parameters, next.js, fetch-api

I am sending the request to register a user from my Next.js frontend like this:

```js
const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/create", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Contet-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ user: {values}),
  });

  const data = await res.json();
```

where the values are username, email, pw, pw confirmation...the usual.
Here are my headers from the request, which confirm that the payload is being sent as expected:

```
General:
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/create
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3001
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Cache-Control: no-cache
Vary: Origin
X-Request-Id: a044ad4b-dbb3-41ed-80bd-ca933871b924
X-Runtime: 115.547357

Request headers:
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,nl;q=0.9,hr;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 27
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Contet-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:3001
Referer: http://localhost:3001/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36

Request payload:
{user:{email:"ggggg@gmail.com", username:"myusername", password:"123123",password_confirmation:"123123"}}
```

But what happens is the parameters from the frontend request *never* show up in my controllers.

So naturally, my first step was to byebug my rails controller in order to figure out what is going on, and when I do that all I see from params is:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"user", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

My user params are nowhere to be seen. What is going on here?

I even started another rails project through a template:
https://github.com/rchuasing/rails-api-boilerplate

and the same thing keeps happening again, I am recieving no parameters in any controller.

Here is my controller that I've stripped down to bare minimum in order to just test the params:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
    def create
        # this is where I look for params
        byebug
    end

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :username, :password, 
                                     :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::JTIMatcher
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :jwt_authenticatable, 
  jwt_revocation_strategy: self
end
```

I have tried everything I could think of, that includes making a new app and trying all kinds of various headers, but the params never get to the backend.

Comment: did you configured [devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791531/how-to-specify-devise-parameter-sanitizer-for-edit-action)

Comment: The issue was with react/next. I user an older version of next, and with that version everything worked normally, so I think the problem was in Next.